# ESP8266 & Initial State

Tags: esp8266

Has anyone been successful in connecting an ESP8266 to the Initial State IoT platform?

On the platform there is only one example with Cactus ESP. I tried it but it did not work because I have a NodeMCU.

Can you please share your Arduino code?

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Arduino IDE Board Manager to install the support for ESP boards 
an ESP8266 can be programmed in EXACTLY the same way as you program an Arduino.

This mean you will now be able to follow the Cactus Micro sample up to the point where you upload CMTempTest.ino.

The problem with the [HubTest.ino](https://github.com/InitialState/piot-athome-arduino/blob/master/HubTest.ino) code is that relies on having a serial link between the Cactus board's main processor and its ESP8266 network slave processor.  You don't have that so all the AT commands are not going to work.

However you do have a number of examples that come with the ESP addition to the IDE and in there will be a network client example.  You need to look at how that code forms a connection and make HubTest.ino work in that way.  I can't tell you exactly what to do (I don't know) but any lines that are AT related need to be replaced by "proper" networking code.